# How to import Python Class or Function from parent directory?

Tags: python

0

I have this project structure,

```
.\src
  .\api
    test.py
  .\config
    config.py
  app.py
```

when i'm trying to import a function or class from test.py inside config.py, using this statement

```
from src.api.test import tes_func
```

I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.api'
```

if i use these 2 lines i can import using

```
from api.test import tes_func.

import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

why it's not working when use from src.api.test import test_func Is there a way to import python files without `sys.path.append("../")`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

You have to use something like this:

```
from ..api.test import tes_func
```